# Smartphone camera app that take square photographs

Tags: photography, camera

Can someone recommend a smartphone camera app that takes square photographs?

The preview window (a.k.a. viewfinder) may be either:

1. a square, or
2. an oblong rectangle with square guides

It is better for it to operate with more mechanic feelings, meaning fewer bells & whistles and filters.

All smartphone operating systems are welcome.

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: @Undo quote: "All smartphone operating systems are welcome." Looks like that camera is the sole purchase criterion ;)

Answer (score 4):

The default iPhone Camera App has a square mode:

[image: iPhone Camera Screen Capture]